# puppet class with class dsdfsfd {} and class { 'dsdfsfd' }

Tags: vagrant, puppet

Very simple question I hope, I am using vagrant and in my puppet file I have the following

```
class iptables {
    package { "iptables":
        ensure => present
    }

    service { "iptables":
        require => Package["iptables"],
        hasstatus => true,
        status => "true",
        hasrestart => false,
    }

    file { "/etc/sysconfig/iptables":
        owner   => "root",
        group   => "root",
        mode    => 600,
        replace => true,
        ensure  => present,
        source  => "/vagrant/files/iptables.txt",
        require => Package["iptables"],
        notify  => Service["iptables"],
    }
}
class { 'iptables': }
```

now my question is what is the different between `class iptables {}` and `class { 'iptables': }` or does one need to come after another ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The order of notation is irrelevant.

```
class { 'iptables': }
```

is just another way or writing

```
include iptables
```

and the latter should generally be preferred.

Answer (score 1):

Please check this explanation about [include](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/latest/reference/lang_classes.html#using-include) function.

There is one important difference between creating an instance with `include` and `class`.
Consider the following examples:

e.g 1:

```
include some_class
include some_class # no additional effect; the class is only declared once
```

e.g. 2:

```
class { "some_class": }
class { "some_class": } # this will not compile !
```

Making an instance by `include` became especially important, when you try to reuse your puppet configurations. E.g you have defined `node1` and `node2`, both makes an instance of class `some_class`. Next you want to create `single_node` containing both nodes.

E.g. `single_node.pp` manifest:

```
include node1
include node2
```

If `some_class` was declared by `class{ 'some_class': }`, it will create a conflict and the manifest will not compile.  On the other hand with `include some_class`, manifest will compile, without any "already defined" errors.

In my opinion using `include` is more than recommended.

Additional reading [require vs include vs class](http://ben-tech.blogspot.com/2012/12/puppet-require-vs-include-vs-class.html)